# show/hide div from right-top, left-top, right-bottom, left-bottm corners on museover effect

Tags: jquery, show-hide, mouseover

I have a list of persons with their images. I want to show each person's description when I hover on each item.
The description in the other div and it can be seen only if I hover on image.

Now the point is I want to show description `divs` from specific corners.
I have tried to use the jQuery `show/hide` functions, but there is no direction attribute to show it from corner.
Here how it should be appear:

[image]

```
$(".persons li.one").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find('div').show("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  })
});

$(".persons li.one").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('div').hide("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to control which corner your animation will start or end, position you 'div' to 'absolute', and use 'left' or 'right, and 'top' and 'bottom' attributes to set which one will stay constant as the size changes.

Example (css):

```
.persons li.one {position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;}
```

Will start or end the animation at the right-bottom corner of your div.

And

```
.persons li.one {position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;}
```

This will start or end the animation at the right-top corner of your div, and so on.

Hope this helps.